# Dialog's close event triggers focus event and leads to endless loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I moved my application to newest jQueryUI versions and now the behavior has changed. Namely when opening a dialog the blur event is called on the element that had the focus. When the dialog is closed, the focus event of that element is called again. These events were not called with the previous jQuery versions.

The problem is that I'm opening the dialog in the focus event, closing it hence calls focus again and endless loop occurs.

How can I prevent this endless loop?

EDIT:

I can't get it right in a simple jsfiddle The best is this one

http://jsfiddle.net/8sfjV/11/

```
<div id="dialog" title="Select Value">
    <select id="select" name="select">
        <option value="1">Test</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="" />

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 120,
        width: 185,
        position: [285, 200],
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close")
            }
        }
    });

    $("#test").focus(function (event) {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Here there is no endless loop but you can see after closing the dialog the page (result) is broken as everything is "blurred out".

Also the old behavior is more like this one:

http://jsfiddle.net/SrSXU/3/

Here the background still remains "blurred out" but you can focus into the input which is not possible with the new versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use click instead of focus. this should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/bDnK9/

```
$("#test").click(function (event) {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: This doesn't help with keyboard navigation or screen reader users.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say whether this was true of earlier jQueryUI versions, but...

> Upon closing a dialog, focus is automatically returned to the element
>   that had focus when the dialog was opened.

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Seems you should use another event to open your dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered setting a state from closing and then checking for it?

If on close of the dialog, you set something like `$("#test").data('coming-from-dialog', true)`, then your focus handler can be something like:

```
$("#test").focus(function (event) {
    var test = $(this);
    if(!!test.data('coming-from-dialog')) {
        // clear state for next focus
        $this.data('coming-from-dialog', false);
        return;
    }

    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Of course you can also on dialog close focus something else on close, or click the document body or so to clear the focus.

Comment: I came up with a control variable set in blur event: http://jsfiddle.net/ZuZdV/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
var idOfTheElementLastModalWasOpenedFor = null;
$(":focusable:not(#test)").focus(function() {
    idOfTheElementLastModalWasOpenedFor = null;
});

$("#test").focus(function (event) {
    thisID = $this.attr("id");
    if(idOfTheElementLastModalWasOpenedFor != thisID){        
        idOfTheElementLastModalWasOpenedFor = thisID;
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    }
});
```

And to improve user experience you might want to do something like this:

```
var idOfTheElementLastModalWasOpenedFor = null;
$(":focusable:not(#test)").focus(function() {
    idOfTheElementLastModalWasOpenedFor = null;
});

function openMyModal(event) {
    $thisID = $this.attr("id");
    if(event.type == "click" || idOfTheElementLastModalWasOpenedFor != $thisID){        
        idOfTheElementLastModalWasOpenedFor = $thisID;
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    }
};    

$("#test").focus(openMyModal);
$("#test").click(openMyModal);
```